# My Nestedsortable is not working, because of cannot call the javascript file

Tags: codeigniter

Iam using CI version 2.1.2

iam following course by tutplus training

this problem is a when i call the javascript file that's not working properly

iam very counfused day to day iam thingking how make it solved, buat iam cannot

here the script of my page_head file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php echo $meta_title; ?></title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="<?php echo site_url('css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo site_url('css/admin.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo site_url('css/datepicker.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo site_url('js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('js/bootstrap-datepicker.js'); ?>"></script>


    <?php if(isset($sortable) && $sortable === TRUE): ?>
    <script src="<?php echo site_url('js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo site_url('js/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js'); ?>"></script>  
    <?php  endif; ?>
```

Please Somebody help me, please make it file .js working

Answer (score 0):

Use `base_url` instead of `site_url`.

For example, replace this...

```
<script src="<?php echo site_url('js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script>
```

...with this...

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script>
```

Do this for all `link` and `script` tag declarations in your `head`.

From the [Codeigniter documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html):

> site_url(): Returns your site URL, as specified in your config file. The index.php file (or whatever you have set as your site index_page in your config file) will be added to the URL, as will any URI segments you pass to the function, and the url_suffix as set in your config file.
>
> base_url(): Returns your site base URL, as specified in your config file. (...) This function returns the same thing as site_url, without the index_page or url_suffix being appended.